# React Native Expo Environment Variables with EAS

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, expo

I have a secret key that I need to use in my app.  On the web, I would use a .env file, but with **React Native and Expo**.

I want to use the EAS Build, and found the following documentation [EAS variables docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/)

This gives information about adding the "secret" to your eas.json file, but I am unable to find 2 important things:

What code to use to access the secret variable in the dev and prod environment.

I'm thinking in production the code would be 'process.env.SECRET_KEY' and hoping the same code would apply for the dev environment, but I am not sure how to get the process.env in dev to be populated with the SECRET_KEY.

When I console.log(process.env) in my app, I just get NODE_ENV: "development".

My thought is that many apps need some sort of Secret bit of info, so any ideas on a best practice or at this point just any way to get this to work!

Answer (score 14):

I was able to get the environment (secret) variable working with the eas build process.

I am sure there are other ways to accomplish this, however this is the approach I took:

I chose to use a `.env` file for the **dev environment** and the `eas secret:create` command for eas builds.

First, you need to create a secret for your project with the eas cli.
[eas secret command](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#adding-secrets-with-eas-cli)

Then, create you .env file with your secret.  Make sure this has the same spelling as the secret created for eas.

You will then use the **app.config.js** file to inject the secret so that your code can access it.  NOTE: I found that I needed to remove the `app.json` file.  I moved all the config from `app.json` to `app.config.js`.

Also remember to run `npm install dotenv` on your terminal to add dotenv to your project.

```js
// the dotenv/config will read your .env file 
// and merge it with process.env data
// This is just for the builds that happen outside of eas
import "dotenv/config";

// the secrets created with eas secret:create will
// be merged with process.env during eas builds
const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

export default {
  name: "TV Tracker",
  slug: "tv-tracker",
  scheme: "tvtracker",
...
  // THIS IS WHAT WE READ IN THE CODE
  // uses the expo constants package
  extra: {
    secretKey: secretKey,
  },
};
```

Now we can read the **secretKey** using the expo-constants module.

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";
...

let secretKey = Constants.expoConfig.extra.secretKey;
```

Comment: Also remember to run npm install dotenv on your terminal to add dotenv to your project.

Comment: Instead of usign expo-constants modules. You can use a babel plugin called transform-inline-environment-variables too.

Comment: How to use dotenv with react native as it gives error, fs module not found.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I actually imported dotenv and tried to configure it as dotenv.config() in my entry file, but seems that causes problems (don't know why), this approach works fine

Comment: This is the simplest approach based on all other threads and responses.

Comment: How do you set different values of an env variable based on the EAS profile? Imagine API_URL for different profiles (beta, staging, prod). I see the secret is just a key pair which can be scoped to the app or to the expo account.

Answer (score 2):

Got my answer here
https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1265#issuecomment-1301525320
I do wish expo simplified/cleaned their documentation a bit and made like one simple example which just works out of the box instead of providing tons of information where it's so easy to miss `Constants.expoConfig` vs `Constants.manifest`

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to @markmccoid's answer, I usually use a bash script to put the .env secrets into eas for the project.

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    eas secret:create --scope project --name "$key" --value "$value"
done < .env
```